# In VS Code, is there a way to set Prettier to not wrap function parameters in parantheses (when using an arrow function)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I code in React and I always use arrow functions. When I use a single parameter in JS function, I like to leave it without parantheses. I always use arrow functions But I use Prettier frequently, and it wraps all my parameters in paranteheses automatically. Is there any way to make Prettier leave the parameter unwrapped?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The option you're looking for is ["Arrow Function Parentheses"](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#arrow-function-parentheses). Go to your Prettier config (e.g. in `.prettierrc` file) and add this key:

```json
"arrowParens": "avoid"
```

Example of what this option does:

```js
// Before formatting
const foo = (x) => 10;
const bar = (x, y) => 20;

// After formatting
const foo = x => 10;
const bar = (x, y) => 20;
```

Read more: [How to add custom Prettier config](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html)

Comment: Thank you, it works. I don't know why I was so lazy to ask it here instead of looking up the settings... Maybe because I didn't think it was possible to od it? But thanks again!